# Levres en retrait meaning

Tags: sens

Recently we came across such an expression *lèvres en retrait*. I have explored all Internet resources, but unfortunately I could not find the answer. Could anyone explain the meaning of this phrase?

Comment: Since it is not a set phrase you must give more context if you want an appropriate answer.

Comment: I don't know any expression like "Lèvres en retrait", it might be a physical description. But according to @Laure, no way to answer this if we don't have the context.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but it could be describing the correct positioning of the lips (of one’s mouth!) to pronounce certain sounds in a particular language. If this be the case, “lèvres en retrait” could mean the “opposite” of “lèvres arrondies/avancées/en avant” (rounded/puckered lips), in which case “[lèvres rétractées](https://books.google.com/books?id=ALKu2yIEjkoC&pg=PA26&dq=%22l%C3%A8vres+en+avant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9rISh6Z_MAhXM6iYKHVjABEUQ6AEIKjAC#v=snippet&q=%22l%C3%A8vres%20r%C3%A9tract%C3%A9es%22&f=false)/écartées” (retracted/spread lips) might be a better term to use.

Comment: Unfortunately there was not a context, because it was given in a list of expressions in the textbook in the theme of appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"lèvres" means "lips" or "labium", it should be obvious with more context which one this is about.
"en retrait" is synonym with "reculé", "enfoncé", "qui se tient à l'écart".

so "lèvres en retrait" could be part of the physical description of someone's face. It is difficult to say more without a more precise context.